# Jarsigner (MIME Content-Type is not application/timestamp-reply)

Tags: java, ssl, jarsigner

Some time ago I wrote a program to sign jars in our build process. Which worked for a couple of months without any problems.

Now the jarsigner outputs (without changing anything!):

```
jarsigner: unable to sign jar: 
java.io.IOException: MIME Content-Type is not application/timestamp-reply
```

and the jars are not signed anymore.

What is the problem and what do I need to do to get the jarsigner working again?

I'm using this timestamp server:
**http://timestamp.comodoca.com**

and this Java version:
**Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM "1.8.0_101" on Linux**

This is my exact command line (which worked for the last months!):
`jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore certificate_file.p12 -storepass mypassword -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com myjarfile.jar myalias`

Comment: Seems they have changed it again, currently waiting for support answer.

Comment: Seems like the problem is caused by a server delay/limitation, since Comodoca advises to wait at least 15 seconds to "not hammer our servers", and I should wait something like 3-5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it works. Seems like they changed something at their timestamp server.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem.  I think something change in Comodo's timestamp service today. The response status for http://timestamp.comodoca.com is currently 
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html

This causes a problem for jarsigner as it is expecting content-type to be application/timestamp-reply

You should contact Comodo support at https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/68/0/time-stamping-server